# Using getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, getdate

I am using the below query

```
SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[QUANTITY] 
    WHERE getdate() BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
```

If the `todate` is `null` (`1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`) it just filters them out. I want even the fields with `todate` to be `null` (`1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`) in the result. How can this be done?

Comment: Well, is it `NULL` or `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`?

Comment: It is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: You can replace them with some date in the future.

Comment: NULL is NOT the same thing as 1/1/1900. Maybe you can use ISNULL or COALESCE? If todate is what date should be used as a comparison?

Comment: WHERE getdate() BETWEEN fromdate AND (CASE todate WHEN '1/1/1900' THEN '12/31/2999' ELSE todate END)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explicitly check it with a combination of `and` and `or` operators:

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[QUANTITY] 
WHERE  (getdate() >= fromdate AND
        (todate IS NULL OR
         todate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
       ) OR
       getdate() BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
```

Comment: I need to use filter to get where today’s date is between the from date and the todate. If the todate is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 it is not including them in the filters. why do I have to use getdate() >=fromdate  here. Please explain thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somewhere along the line there is a .Net or some program saving the Date.MinValue, if the application cannot be replaced you could always tack on a

```
datefromparts(1900,1,1)
```

and change the where clause to:

```
where getdate() > fromdate
and (todate = datefromparts(1900,1,1) or getdate() <= todate)
```

that would take either the max or unbounded for the todate.  if it is possible, to prevent odd results, i would also use

```
declare @testDate datetime = getdate();
```

and use that variable in the preceding where clause instead of getdate().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[QUANTITY] 
WHERE getdate() >= fromdate
  AND getdate() <= COALESCE(todate
                           ,NULLIF(todate,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
                           ,'9999-12-31 23:59:59.997'
                           )
```